# Regex for finding and replacing SQL Server username and password in connection strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

We just changed our MS SQL Database passwords for 2 ID's. I have over 50 asp.net web applications running off the database which all need the connection strings updated. Is there a handy regex I could use to seach for the server ID, username and password?

Its a long story but I need to be able to match those 3 elements and the connection strings arent all in the same format (some have password before username and vice versa).

This is an example of one of our connection strings:

`Data Source=dbserver;Initial Catalog=HOL;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Password=password`

I've tried this from [regular-expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/near.html) but I really am a novice with regex.

`\b(?:password\W+(?:\w+\W+){1,6}?user|user\W+(?:\w+\W+){1,6}?password)\b`

**Edit:** I have a find and replace tool (fnr.exe) that I can use, I just need a regex for finding the strings...

Comment: Do you have to care about synonyms as well (`UID`, `PWD`, `Server`, `Address`,  `Addr`, `Network Address`)?

Comment: can you provide more connection string examples so that we are able to improve our answers?

Comment: Apologies, yes they all have the same synonyms (User ID, Password and Data Source)

Answer (score 1):

Here are separate regex for matching

- Data Source

  `\bData\hSource=\w+\b`
- User ID

  `\bUser\hID=\w+\b`
- Password

  `\bPassword=\w+\b`

You can combine them as follows (similar to the example you provided):

```
\b(?:(User\hID=\w+);(Password=\w+)|(Password=\w+);(User\hID=\w+))\b
```

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/bT3yI1/1

Answer (score 0):

The following Regex should help:

```
/;?(Data Source|User ID|Password)=((?:&(?:[a-z]+|#[0-9]+);|[^;]){0,})/gi
```

As a bonus this will also catch HTML entities, e.g. `&amp;`.

Tested in: https://regex101.com/r/vE2tT0/2

Answer (score 0):

If you just have to do it once, I'd recommend just running consecutive search and replaces for data source (`\bData\hSource=\w+\b`) user id (`\bUser\hID=\w+\b`) and password (`\bPassword=\w+\b`).

To write one regex that matches all possible combinations is way more effort.

Comment: There are different combinations, for example server1 with userID1 and password1. Then another could be server1 with userID2 and password2. Doing a generic find and replace is what I have right now and is taking too long